# how to write a javascript for copying a substring using substring() and substr() methods

Tags: javascript

can anyone tell me what am i getting error while using script tag here ?

```
<HTML>
<head> <title> prac 5 ques 3 </title> </head>
<body>
<script>​
var name1="Shashank Shyamsundar Phatkure";​
var name2="Shashany";​
var n=name1.substring(15,22)​
document.write("<br/>Name1:" +name1);​
document.write("<br/>Surname:" +n);​
document.write("<br/>Name2:" +name2);​
document.write("<br/>Copying the surname for name2:");​
var name3=name2+" " +n​
document.write("<br/>Name3:" +name3);​
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **What** error are you getting? Which line causes the error? What do you expect to happen? What _actually_ happens?

Comment: The only errors that I found was when copying and pasting a bunch of odd characters where added to the end of the javascript lines.

Comment: Your code has invisible Unicode characters in it.

Comment: There are a bunch of `&#8203;` characters — Zero-Width Space — but I can't tell if they were there from the OP or if Stackoverflow _put_ them there. They are outside of the `clss="hljs-string` span (high-light java-script string / syntax highlighting)

Comment: Voting to close as a typo — there is nothing wrong with the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution. You can get `surname` using `substring()` or `substr()`.

`string.substr(start, length)`

`string.substring(start, end)`

```js
var name1="Shashank Shyamsundar Phatkure";
var name2="Shashany";
// var n=name1.substring(21,29);
var n=name1.substr(21,8);
document.write("<br/>Name1:" +name1);
document.write("<br/>Surname:" +n);
document.write("<br/>Name2:" +name2);
document.write("<br/>Copying the surname for name2:");
var name3=name2+" " +n;
document.write("<br/>Name3:" +name3);
```

```html
<HTML>
<head> <title> prac 5 ques 3 </title> </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```